# Why is horizontal line only partially displayed in sage / matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, sage

I have the following `sage` code that generates a `matplotlib` graph of the function:

[image: stupid that I can't use LATEX on this site and have to upload a gif :(]

I additionally wish to plot the point `(a, f(a))` when a = 4.0001, and a dashed red line from the y-axis through this point. Here is the code that I wrote to do this:

```
f(x) = (x**2 - 2*x - 8)/(x - 4)
g = plot(f, x, -1, 5)

a = 4.0001  
L = plot(f(a), color='red', linestyle="--")
pt = point((a, f(a)), pointsize=25)

g += pt + L
g.show(xmin=0, ymin=0)
```

However, this outputs the following graph with the horizontal line only partially displayed (it does not intersect the point `pt`):

[image: graph of function f(x) = (x**2 - 2*x - 8)/(x - 4)]

***Why is this horizontal line only partially displayed?***

What do I need to do to correctly graph the line of constant function `y = f(4.0001)`?

Comment: try plotting it last. I dunno sage, but I assume if you plot first without specifying the x range, it uses a default of [0,1].

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "plot it last"? As it stands, it already is the last part appended to the graph, so I'm not sure what you're suggesting I do differently.

Comment: @Julien -- almost! Sage actually uses a default of [-1, 1]. The negative part is not shown here because of the `xmin=0` in `g.show(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to use matplotlib's `hlines` function, for which you simply need to specify the `y`-value and the `xmin` and `xmax`, i.e.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return (x**2 - 2*x - 8)/(x - 4)

x = np.linspace(-5,5, 100)
a = 4.001

plt.plot(x, f(x), -1, 5, linestyle='-')
plt.hlines(6, min(x), max(x), color='red', linestyle="--", linewidth=1)
plt.scatter(a, f(a))
plt.xlim([0, plt.xlim()[1]])
plt.ylim([0, plt.ylim()[1]])
plt.show()
```

Which will give you

[image: HLine with function]

---

Note that some adjustments were made to use matplotlib directly throughout the example - they are not critical.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know, though, why it doesn't work to just define the constant function `f(x) = C` and then plot the line? Is there some reason that matplotlib only displays constant functions on interval [0,1], but all other functions are plotted across entire window? I couldn't find anything in docs about this.

Comment: @J.Taylor Maplotlib’s `plot` function expects both x and y value(s), giving it only the y value(s) will result in it guessing what interval to use, if you do `plt.plot( np.linspace(min(x), max(x), f(a))` it would plot a horizontal line at `f(a)` over the entire interval. I only recommended `hlines` because it is the dedicated tool for plotting horizontal lines in matplotlib.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I think you're right that using `hlines` makes more sense. Thanks very much for taking time to explain!

Answer (score 1):

Sage lets the user specify the range of x values when plotting.

Failing any indication, it will plot from -1  to 1.

After plotting f for x-values from -1 to 5:

```
g = plot(f, x, -1, 5)
```

why not plot the constant f(a) also from -1 to 5:

```
L = plot(f(a), x, -1, 5, color='red', linestyle="--")
```

A line from (0, f(a)) to (a, f(a)) can also be plotted simply as:

```
L = line([(0, f(a)), (a, f(a))], color='red', linestyle='--')
```